# JSONP not working with crossDomain request in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting responses from JSONP crossDomain request with jQuery `ajax` with below

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://ipinfo.io/{/literal}{$smarty.server.REMOTE_ADDR}{literal}/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(response){

                $("#apply_modal").modal({
                    remote: load_url
                });
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

This doesn't seem to be working at all in IE10 but works on all other browsers.

Also when I open `DebugBar` it works again.

I cannot understand why. There are no errors with the above javascript

What would be the issue?

Comment: I would stay away from JSONP. You may want to consider CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). JSONP has security problems, and CORS is becoming the standard for cross-domain implementations. The downside is it's not supported by IE6-9, but there are polyfills available.

Comment: although you can change to this also `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is the `console.log` not the JSONP. IE only includes the `console` when the developer toolbar is open. Try creating a stub, or use an alert instead and you should have no problem